# Spring Boot вместе с Spring Data JPA Repository NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

я пишу бота и использую Spring Boot вместе с Spring Data Jpa Repository. Подключенные зависимости:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CARS_ADS?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

У меня есть интерфейс наследованные от JpaRepository :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BotStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<BotStatus, Long> {
}
```

И есть класс, который использует в себе методы этого интерфейса:

```
@Service
public class BotStatusDao implements BotStatusService {

    @Autowired
    private BotStatusRepository repository;

    @Override
    public BotStatus save(BotStatus botStatus) {
        return repository.save(botStatus);
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь сохранить в бд:

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Autowired
    private BotStatusDao dao; // =null
    private BotStatus botStatus;
    private final String BOT_NAME = "test_bot";
    private final String BOT_TOKEN = "";

    public Bot(DefaultBotOptions defaultBotOptions) {
        super(defaultBotOptions);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    // Метод, который вызывается при запросе пользователя
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        ....
        // Проверяем на наличие нажатой кнопки
        else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            // Проверяем полученное значение кнопки
            if (update.getCallbackQuery().getData().startsWith("1")) {
                // Отправляем сообщение в зависимости от значения кнопкиAutowired
                botStatus = new BotStatus();
                String chatId = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId().toString();
                botStatus.setUserId(chatId);
                botStatus = dao.save(botStatus); = NullPointerException
                askAboutBrand(chatId);
                botStatus.setStatus(BotStatusEnums.ASK_ABOUT_MODEL.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и сам Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "by.overone.it")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        Bot bot = new Bot(new DefaultBotOptions());
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
    }
}
```

Когда вызываю dao.save - получаю NullPointerException. Spring не подкидывает бины через @Autowired. Впервые использую Spring Data Jpa. Возможно я что то упустил, возможно надо как то инициализировать объекты в Application ?

Comment: Контейне внедрения зависимостей (CDI) инжектит все зависимости в запрашиваемый объект. В данном случае вы сами создаёте объект класса `TelegramBotsApi`, а значит вся ответственность за подтягивание зависимостей лежит на вас.

Comment: Добавьте классу `TelegramBotsApi` аннотацию `@Component` (так же придётся повозится, чтобы в конструктор пробросить нужный аргумент или сделайте конструктор без аргументов) и используйте в коде где вам нужно. Из main уберите.

Comment: @ArchDemon если вам не будет трудно, можете ли показать пример ? я не совсем понимаю

Comment: Что именно не совсем понимаете?

Comment: @ArchDemon TelegramBotsApi является сторонней библиотекой и просто повесить Component я не могу. Мне тогда надо создавать BeanFactory, что бы вернуть его Bean ?

Comment: Извиняйте, я ошибся. Конечно, вам нужен компонент над классом, в котором происходит исключение. И это класс `Bot`

Comment: @ArchDemon хорошо, а как потом Bot вызывать в Application, что бы все зависимости подтянулись ?

Comment: Вы можете создать новый бин через аннотацию `@Bean` в классе конфигурации (`@Configuration`) или классе `Application`. В качестве аргумента заинжектить Bot, а в качестве возвращаемого значения указать `TelegramBotsApi`

Comment: @ArchDemon посмотрите мой ответ ниже. У меня получилось запустить, но не совсем понял почему именно таким способом получилось, возможно вы разъясните

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "by.overone.it.entity")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "by.overone.it")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "by.overone.it.repository")
public class Application {
@SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(@Autowired BotSession botSession) {
        return args -> {
            botSession.start();
        };
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public BotSession botSession(@Autowired Bot bot) {
        return new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class).registerBot(bot);
    }
}
```

Я упустил тот момент, что в @ComponentScan я указал не корректный путь, в связи с чем, bean бота не находило и кидало ошибку. Моя невнимательность... Спасибо большое `ArchDemon` за помощь

Comment: видимо потому, что вы выходите за пределы спрингового контекста. как только вы создали объект через new уже не имеет значения, что вы пытаетесь заинжектить в нем (либо выполнить любые другие действия с помощью спринга), потому что спринг про такой объект ничего не знает.

Comment: Зачем вы опять создаёте бин для Bot вручную? Предоставьте это дело CDI. Первый бин у вас работает потому, что всё там разруливает CDI (в частности инжект в класс Bot). По итогу вам нужно соединить бин 1 и 2, а 3 - убрать. Берёте за основу бин 2. Аргументом идёт `@Autowired Bot bot` (контекст выгодно пробрасывать в некоторых случаях, но не в вашем). В методе через `new` создаёте `TelegramBotsApi`, регистрируете бота и возвращаете объект `TelegramBotsApi` из метода. Всё.

Comment: @ArchDemon исправил. Теперь, вроде, все спринг разруливает